# Including external (hosted) javascript files in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to add an external js file into my Angular2 project by adding the record to my angular-cli.json file.

I've added a file to the [scripts] array as below:

```
"scripts": ["https://as-identitydemo--c.na50.visual.force.com/resource/1495420277000/salesforce_login_widget_js"],
```

all the other posts that i've read refer to using this format for something that's either hosted locally, or installed in the node_modules etc..

How can I include an external js library and utilize that in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the library in your index.html in the head tag. 
Second you have to make the library visible to your Angular project. That means you need the typings. You can either search https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped 
 for already existing types or add the types to the typings.d.ts file.

Example:

In your page (outside of the Angular app) you might have a javascript global variable:

```
var testVar = 'testvalue';
```

Then in the typings.d.ts you can make this variable globally accessible by adding

```
declare var testVar:string;
```

Then you can access this variable in the whole Angular project like that:

```
console.log(testVar);
```

The same you can do with functions in external libraries.

Here is a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIX8MK3ZNjfgB63qIJC8?p=info) that shows that (without having a typings file). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But it should be the head tag, not a header tag.