# External javascript and html loading in angular 4/5

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, widget

I need to load some html and javascript dynamically in an angular 4/5 component and make it run. Below is a widget code provided by third party that creates a stock chart. It works fine in a basic html page. How do I load this dynamically in angular. Eventually this content would come from database.

Example 1

```
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
              <div id="tradingview_f4496"></div>
              <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a `href="https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>`
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                new TradingView.widget(
                  {
                    "width": 980,
                    "height": 610,
                    "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
                    "interval": "D",
                    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
                    "theme": "Light",
                    "style": "1",
                    "locale": "in",
                    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
                    "enable_publishing": false,
                    "allow_symbol_change": true,
                    "container_id": "tradingview_f4496"
                  }
                );
              </script>
            </div>
```

Example 2

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://in.tradingview.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Market Data</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js" async>
  {
  "showChart": true,
  "locale": "in",
  "largeChartUrl": "",
  "width": "400",
  "height": "660",
  "plotLineColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 1)",
  "plotLineColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 1)",
  "gridLineColor": "rgba(233, 233, 234, 1)",
  "scaleFontColor": "rgba(233, 233, 234, 1)",
  "belowLineFillColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 0.05)",
  "belowLineFillColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 0.05)",
  "symbolActiveColor": "rgba(242, 250, 254, 1)",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "title": "Indices",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "INDEX:SPX",
          "d": "S&P 500"
        },
        {
          "s": "INDEX:IUXX",
          "d": "Nasdaq 100"
        },
        {
          "s": "INDEX:DOWI",
          "d": "Dow 30"
        },
        {
          "s": "INDEX:NKY",
          "d": "Nikkei 225"
        },
        {
          "s": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
          "d": "Apple"
        },
        {
          "s": "NASDAQ:GOOG",
          "d": "Google"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Indices"
    },
    {
      "title": "Commodities",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "CME_MINI:ES1!",
          "d": "E-Mini S&P"
        },
        {
          "s": "CME:E61!",
          "d": "Euro"
        },
        {
          "s": "COMEX:GC1!",
          "d": "Gold"
        },
        {
          "s": "NYMEX:CL1!",
          "d": "Crude Oil"
        },
        {
          "s": "NYMEX:NG1!",
          "d": "Natural Gas"
        },
        {
          "s": "CBOT:ZC1!",
          "d": "Corn"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Commodities"
    },
    {
      "title": "Bonds",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "CME:GE1!",
          "d": "Eurodollar"
        },
        {
          "s": "CBOT:ZB1!",
          "d": "T-Bond"
        },
        {
          "s": "CBOT:UD1!",
          "d": "Ultra T-Bond"
        },
        {
          "s": "EUREX:GG1!",
          "d": "Euro Bund"
        },
        {
          "s": "EUREX:II1!",
          "d": "Euro BTP"
        },
        {
          "s": "EUREX:HR1!",
          "d": "Euro BOBL"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Bonds"
    },
    {
      "title": "Forex",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "FX:EURUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:GBPUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDJPY"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCHF"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:AUDUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCAD"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Forex"
    }
  ]
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Comment: Just have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293797/how-to-import-and-use-particles-js-in-an-angular-angular2-angular4-app

Comment: does not work for me. I need include ll html, script references, inner script dynamically. I will hundreds of these js widgets that need to be loaded from backend database using angular.

Comment: anyone? please use the second example