# How to setup plnkr with Angular and ThreeJS

Tags: angular, three.js, plnkr.co

I'm trying to setup up a simple Plnkr project with Angular and ThreeJS. 
I've got this so far - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Jm4D2zgLtiKBGghC?preview

But as soon as I uncomment `//var scene = new THREE.Scene();` on app.ts There is an error in the console. It's quite hard to understand the error, but I'm presuming it's simply I haven't imported the ThreeJS library correctly.

I've added in `<script src=" https://unpkg.com/three@0.93.0/build/three.js"></script>` to the index.html, I'm not sure what else to do.

On my local environment all I had to do was to use `npm three install` then I was able to import the lib correctly  `import * as THREE from 'three';`

Comment: Just follow the steps described in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293797/how-to-import-and-use-particles-js-in-an-angular-angular2-angular4-app

Comment: If you comment out `import * as THREE from 'three';`, it seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell systemjs where to find `three` package:

**config.js**

```
map: {
  ...
  'three': 'npm:three'
},
```

**[Forked Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/TyxcDMvWFWsuTlw0?preview)**