# how to access variable in template script tag using angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

In index.html

```
<script>
    var variable='some value';
</script>
```

How can I access **variable** in angular code? I tried **windows.variable**, which come with compiling error. I've seen $window.variable on angular 2. But I can't find any usage of **$window** in angular 4.
Is there any solution to get access to pre-defined variable in html code with angular 4?

Comment: use `var` instead of `const` for global variables, `const` variables are not attached to the `window` object

Comment: @Maximus ty for tip, but using var didn't solve my problem

Comment: what was your problem?

Comment: I need to fetch **variable** in my angular service code @Maximus

Comment: Just put the code 'declare var variable:any' to your Angular code like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170294/including-external-hosted-javascript-files-in-angular2

Comment: its window.variable