# Angular 2+: include remotely hosted js file

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to reference a remotely hosted js file in angular-cli.json ?

I tried including the path in the angular-cli.json, but its throwing error while compiling

if its not possible to include it in angular-cli.json, is there any other way to include a remotely hosted js file to be used in a component ?

Answer (score 1):

You can include it in a `<script>` tag in de index.html file.

for more information have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170294/including-external-hosted-javascript-files-in-angular2)